# Chartist.js grid color

Tags: chartist.js

I would like to change grid color on Chartist.js from default grey. I tried to override ct-grid-color setting, but probably did something incorrectly. Can anyone please suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

grid lines:

```
.ct-grids line {
  color: steelblue;
}
```

.. and don't forget the labels! ..

grid labels:

```
.ct-labels span {
  color: steelblue;
}
```

---

The reason why targeting only ".ct-grid" won't work is due to css specificity.  Basically the more specific the css, the more important it becomes so ..

**.ct-grids line { }**  >  **.ct-grids { }**

If it's a little confusing, a nifty little tool is Keegan Street's [css specificity calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st).

Comment: I got it to work using .ct-grids line {
  stroke: steelblue;
} Thank you Butsuri

Answer (score 6):

Just insert in your CSS.

```
.ct-grid{ stroke: red;}
```